# CircuitBreaker::rescuing exceptions {:name=>"Beats input", :exception=>LogStash::Inputs::Beats::InsertingToQueueTakeTooLong, :level=>:warn}

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am new to ELK stack. I am trying to setup FileBeat --> Logstash --> ElasticSearch --> Kibana. Here while trying to send FileBeat output to Logstash input I am getting below error on Logstash side:

```
CircuitBreaker::rescuing exceptions {:name=>"Beats input", :exception=>LogStash::Inputs::Beats::InsertingToQueueTakeTooLong, :level=>:warn}
Beats input: The circuit breaker has detected a slowdown or stall in the pipeline, the input is closing the current connection and rejecting new connection until the pipeline recover. {:exception=>LogStash::Inputs::BeatsSupport::CircuitBreaker::HalfOpenBreaker, :level=>:warn}
```

I am using Logstash 2.3.2 version with FileBeat: 1.2.2, elasticsearch: 2.2.1
my logstash config:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
#    codec => multiline {
#      pattern => "^%{TIME}"
#      negate => true
#      what => previous
#    }
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "^%{TIME:time}\s+%{LOGLEVEL:level}" }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["host:9200"]
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```

my filebeat config:

```
filebeat:  
    prospectors:    
        -      paths:        - *.log      
        input_type: log      
    tail_files: false
output:  
    logstash:    
        hosts: ["host:5044"]    
        compression_level: 3
shipper:
logging:  
    to_files: true  
    files:    
        path: /tmp    
        name: mybeat.log  
        level: error
```